# React-Redux authentication with JWT

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux

I'm trying to build a login system for my React application. I'm using React, Redux, Redux-Thunk and React Router. After login i'm storing a JWT in localstorage.

The problem is that I can't find a good way to "reauthenticate" a user after coming back to the website. Were would be a good spot to call a action creator to fetch user data? Right now i'm just checking if there is a token in localstorage, and changing a value in my reducer. But where would you implement logic for fetching user profile? Here is my main component attached.

```
import React from 'react'
import MainCallPage from './MainCallPage'
import LoginPage from './LoginPage'
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent'
import MainPage from './MainPage'
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { history } from '../helpers/history'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
)

const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_USER' })
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={MainCallPage}></PrivateRoute>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/" component={MainPage} exact />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You could either create a higher-order component that wraps your app and performs a check-up on the token from localStorage together with fetching the user (it would wrap all children of `Router` component), or have the same thing in a custom hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any issue with the current approach but Since you are using a functional Component i would recommend that you use a `useEffect` hook and check if the `token` is present in `localStorage` and if it is present you want to then fetch the user data

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";

useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (token) {
   store.dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_USER' })
    //Fetch Data
   }  
  }, [token])
```

Comment: But I still need to refactor a HOC to wrap everything in I guess? The problem is that in the APP component now I can’t call a redux action since I’m outside the Provider tag. Or is it any other way to do that? Is there any good practices for this?

Comment: I think Placing the above code in your `HeaderComponent`  should do the trick since it seems to consistent in every route and also you want to wrap your `Routes` in a  `Switch` as well.

Comment: is there any good practice for this? i don't know to be honest, but i think it depends on the programmatic approach rather than anything else , I for instance would even use a very different structure setting up the `redux`